# Why is $\langle xN\rangle$ necessarily a subgroup of $G/N$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm having some trouble understanding [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1787711/568976) to [If a maximal subgroup is normal, it has prime index](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213358/if-a-maximal-subgroup-is-normal-it-has-prime-index).

> Notation: We denote the normal subgroup by $N$ instead.
>
> By the Correspondence Theorem, there exists a bijection from the set of all subgroups $H$ such that $N\subseteq H\subseteq G$ onto the set of all subgroups of $G/N$. Since the only such subgroups are $H=N$ and $H=G$, $G/N$ has only two subgroups, namely $N/N$ and $G/N$.
>
> **Let $xN$ be a nontrivial element in $G/N$. $\langle xN\rangle$ is a nontrivial subgroup of $G/N$, thus $\langle xN\rangle=G/N$.** This means $G/N$ is cyclic. If $|G/N|$ is infinite, then $G/N\cong\mathbb{Z}$ which is a contradiction as $\mathbb{Z}$ has infinite subgroups of the form $n\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore $[G:N]=|G/N|$ is finite.

**Question**:

I understand that $xN$ is a non-trivial element in $G/N$. However, what proof do we have that $(xN)^2 = x^2N$, $(xN)^3 = x^3N$ and other higher order terms *exist* in the group $G/N$? And without proving that first, I don't think it makes sense to say that $\langle xN\rangle$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your problem. If $N$ is normal then $G/N$ is equipped with the quotient group structure given by $gN\cdot hN:=ghN$. And so $(xN)^m=x^mN$ by the definition (plus some trivial induction).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *any* element $g\in G$, $gN$ is *some* coset of $G$, and thereby is *some* element of $G/N$, which is by definition the group of all cosets of the normal subgroup $N$ in $G$.

Comment: Okay, but if $g \in G$ we don't know if $g^2 \in G$ too (?). So how can we say that $g^2N \in G/N$?

Comment: @S.D. Remember the group axioms.

Comment: Are you talking about the closure axiom? But it only says that if two *distinct* elements of $G$ i.e. $a$ and $b$ are in $G$ then $ab$ is also in $G$. Or do $a$ and $b$ need not necessarily be distinct in this context?

Comment: @S.D. They don't have to be distinct.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For any $x\in G$, we have $xN\in G/N$.  But once you have your hands on an element of a group, you can always consider the cyclic subgroup it generates.