# Groups with only two subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to find **all** groups $G$ which have only two subgroups $G$ and $\{e\}$.

I think there can be some connection with simple groups, but it's only my intuition. I would like also to prove why these groups have only such two subgroups.

Comment: Here's a start: consider the generated subgroup of an element that is not the identity. That must equal to $G$.

Comment: so it is one of the possibilities?

Comment: What do you mean by possibilities?

Comment: I want to find **all** groups $G$ s. t. they have only two subgroups: $\{e\}$ and $G$. The answer is _generated subgroup of an element that is not the identity_ and nothing more?

Comment: Integers modulo a prime under addition qualify

Comment: I mean you must consider this generated subgroup(s) for any nontrivial group $G$. Use that to reach the conclusion that $G$ must be a finite prime cyclic group.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, notice that for $G=\lbrace e \rbrace$, then $G$ has only one subgroup, so it is not solution.

So let's suppose that $G\neq\lbrace e \rbrace$ and $G$ has only two subgroups. Then take $x \in G \setminus \lbrace e \rbrace$. The subgroup generated by $x$ must be different from $\lbrace e \rbrace$, therefore it must be equal to $G$. This means that $G$ is generated by one element : if $G$ is infinite, then $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, and $\mathbb{Z}$ has a lot of subgroups, so $G$ is not a solution. So $G$ is finite, so $G$ is cyclic. If its order is not a prime number, you can easily find several subgroups ; whereas if its order is a prime number, you cannot.

So the solutions are the cyclic groups of prime orders.

Comment: Thank you very much!